# Does a raw SQL query used in the Microsoft Entity Framework return objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I personally like SQL, but I realize I probably need to follow the EF design.  At times and with other team members, SQL *will* be used.  When a Raw SQL Query is made, does it return objects/properties for my C# code?  If I have five tables mapped, and I do a raw query, are corresponding properties returned?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes. You need to define your entity class for the result of your raw SQL Query, remember to make the name of the properties exactly the same with the name of returned columns in your query.

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntity>("your query").ToList();
```

Comment: Are you saying I have to create a class that will have all the columns for just that query?  In other words, I have to create a class that has the columns for the five tables in that single class?

Comment: @johnny, yes you need to do it. I don't know a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: But if I do not use Raw SQL, can I get the data from the already mapped individual tables, not special classes?

Comment: @johnny, I am not sure what you mean. If you don't use raw sql query, of course you can still use Linq to Sql to work with your mapped tables.

Answer (score 1):

With EF, you have to create and maintain the POCO for your raw query, and your query text will probably languish inside double quotes somewhere. Why not grab [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst)? Your sql will be in .sql file, and the wrapper code, including POCO will be generated and managed for you. And there are *numerous other advantages*!

You don't have to use one approach exclusively. Lots of folk use EF, then Dapper or something like it when they need/want to "revert" to SQL. QueryFirst isn't an ORM and doesn't replace EF. Obviously if you let EF manage your schema, (code first, model first) then non-EF queries risk being walloped by EF schema changes. But with QueryFirst at least, you can "recompile" your queries to assure they're working and still return what you need after EF has changed your schema.

Disclaimer: I wrote QueryFirst.

Comment: I have no idea other than I would like things to be objects instead of me parsing strings and not knowing datatypes.  It seemed it would add productivity, since I am using Visual Studio, but the overhead of the ORM (I am not a fan of ORMs) seems like a whole lot of trouble without a lot of payoff.

Comment: QueryFirst. Don't hesitate. You just stated all the reasons. It's not an ORM, and there's no overhead.